# Logitech Anywhere 2 mouse No options using Mac High Sierra

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

I seem to have lost my ability to see my battery, change mouse options.

I have the Logitech Control Center Installed for Mac High Sierra, and I have the Options App in the applications folder.  None of these will accept the Anywhere MX 2.  The mouse works, but I lost all the configuration software.  Is there a way to get it back, make it work.

logitech-options_mac_v8.36.76.zip
Options_8.30.293.zip

Ideas?

No support from Logitech.